# How to generate order id by signing in as guest in android app-shopping cart

Tags: php, android, magento, android-ksoap2

I'm developing an shopping cart app, as a registered customer I can generate the order id, but I  don't know how to use the guest customer.I use the following code to set the guest customer.

```
SoapObject res = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SHOPPING_CART_CUSTOMER_SET);
res.addProperty("mode", "guest");
res.addProperty("customer_id",62);
res.addProperty("email", "muthu1984mca@gmail.com");
res.addProperty("firstname", "Muthamizhan");
res.addProperty("lastname", "Chelladurai");
res.addProperty("confirmation", true);
res.addProperty("website_id",1);
res.addProperty("store_id",1);
res.addProperty("group_id",1);

request = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SHOPPING_CART_CUSTOMER_SET);
request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
request.addProperty("quoteId", shoppingCartID);
request.addProperty("customer",res);
// request.addProperty("storeId","1");

// request.addProperty("paymentData",values);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
transport.debug = true;
transport.call(SOAP_NAMESPACE + SOAP_PREFIX + SHOPPING_CART_CUSTOMER_SET,  envelope);

// getting the response which is the customerId
Log.d("Setting Customer", "request:" + transport.requestDump);
Log.d("Setting Customer", "response:" + transport.responseDump);
```

Comment: check http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.html

Comment: @user3383912 If i do by this method also, the guest is not setting

Answer (score 0):

For guest customers no need of this method "shoppingCartCustomerSet". Skip this step and directly you can add billing and shipping addresses, shipping method, payment method and then generate order. It will automatically set the customer as guest.